# php anonymous function parameters

Tags: php, function

I'm trying to understand Anonymous Functions in php (laravel framework) , I searched about my basic question here but I didn't find the answer.

```
echo preg_replace_callback('~-([a-z])~', function ($match) {
    return strtoupper($match[1]);
}, 'hello-world');
// outputs helloWorld
```

What parameters gone inside the anonymous function ??

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/', function () {
    return 'Hello World';
});
```

Comment: It depends on what's calling the anonymous function. Read the description of `preg_replace_callback` to see what arguments it sends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://php.net/preg_replace_callback

> A callback that will be called and passed an array of matched elements in the subject string. The callback should return the replacement string. This is the callback signature:

So it sends in the array of matches.